# Grammar to continue a token (i.e. ID) on the next line by escaping (ignoring) continuation symbol & new line (' \n')

Tags: escaping, newline, antlr4

IBM i control language (CL) statements terminate with `\n` (newline) and uses `+\n` or `-\n` to continue a long statement on the next line (`-` continues with position 1 of the next line, `+` continues with the 1st non-blank character on the next line). I used the ANTLR4 RC1 "Fun with Python Newlines" example in the book which is a close match and it works OK, provided the `+` or `-` continuation character does not split a token text. For example, this is valid in CL:

```
    chg+                                                   
    var +                                                
    &x (&-                                             
    x++                                                    
       1) /* "Change variable" statement resulting in: chgvar &X (&X+1) */
```

-or-

```
    chgvar &y (&a || 'some +
    stuff') /* result: chgvar &y (&a || 'some stuff') */
```

Here is the grammar for a simple test rig, supporting only `ID` and `-` as line escape:

NOTE: Based of lexmagic/SimplePy.g4

```
    grammar CL;
    pgm       :   stat+ EOF ;
    stat      :   ID NEWLINE ;
    ID        :   [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
    NEWLINE   :   '\r'? '\n' ;
    WS        :   [ \t]+ -> skip ;
    LINE_ESC  :   '-' '\r'? '\n' -> skip ;
```

This is how to run it (after all the exports and alias's needed in terminal):

```
    antlr4 CL.g4
    javac *.java
    grun CL pgm -tree
    abc- (Return once)
    def (Return, CTRL-D)
    line 2:0 extraneous input 'def' expecting NEWLINE
    (pgm (stat abc def \n) <EOF>)
```

ANTLR4 sees the `ID` as two tokens `abc`, `def` instead of `abcdef`, and I understand why (when the Lexer sees `-\n` it emits the `ID` token for `abc`, discards the `-\n` and starts `def` as a new token.). The parser sees `abc` `def\n` instead of `abcdef\n`.

The question is, is there a way to have the parser see `abc-\ndef\n` as one token instead of two?

On the other hand, if the source code = `abc -\ndef\n` then it should legitimately emit 2 tokens because of the space between `abc` and `-\n`.

Comment: To make it easier to differentiate code from description, you should use Stack Overflow's code formatting. You can use backticks (`) for inline code and 4 spaces at the beginning of a line for code blocks. This will make it a lot easier to understand what you're trying to say. I started you off with an edit (may be pending approval), but since I don't know the code that well, you'll need to finish it off.

Answer (score 2):

I would lean towards using a custom [`CharStream`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/index.html) implementation to hide the continuation characters from the lexer, which works like the standard streams except for:

- The implementation of [`IntStream.LA(i)`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#LA%28int%29) needs to skip the continuation characters when necessary for both positive and negative `i`.
- The implementation of [`IntStream.consume`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#consume%28%29) needs to skip past the hidden region when necessary, i.e. after using a regular implementation of `consume`, if the next two characters are `-\n` or `+\n` then immediately move the index past the skipped characters.
- The implementation of [`IntStream.seek`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#seek%28int%29) needs to ensure the index is left on a visible character (see the Javadocs for more information).
- The implementation of [`CharStream.getText`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStream.html#getText%28org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.Interval%29) should return the text from the specified interval with the invisible continuation characters stripped from the result.
- The implementation of [`IntStream.mark`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#mark%28%29), [`IntStream.release`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#release%28int%29), [`IntStream.index`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#index%28%29), [`IntStream.size`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#size%28%29) and [`IntStream.getSourceName`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#getSourceName%28%29) don't need anything special.

You may need to perform additional steps to ensure the line and column numbers associated with your tokens are correct since the lexer won't see every input symbol.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, and your strategy makes a sense. However, I am not a Java programmer but I will give it a try (once I can figure out where to start, heh heh).